# ? вместо эмодзи

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Гугл скрипт связан вебхуком с телеграм ботом. Я хочу, чтобы сообщение из бота разбивалось на нужные мне куски и отправлялось в гугл таблицу.
Проблема возникает с извлечением эмодзи

```
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var text = contents.message.text
  var textar = text.split("");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
  sheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).appendRow([text,textar[4]]);
```

Таким образом мне приходит оригинальный текст + конкретный символ(на котором обязательно будет эмодзи). Однако в таблице появляется "?", хотя в соседней ячейке эмодзи прекрасно отображается в рамках всего сообщения.
Как изменить код, чтобы скрипт верно отправлял на запись именно эмодзи и не терял его?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text.split("");` правильно разбивает только те строки, которые состоят из юникод-символов, закодированных двумя байтами в кодировке UTF-16 (code unit). Эмодзи, как правило, кодируются четырмя байтами (2 code units), поэтому разбиваются на две части так называемой суррогатной пары, каждая из которых не может быть самостоятельным символом и представляется знаком вопроса при отображении. Правильная разбивка может быть сделана при помощи `[...text]` выражения, так как в современном JavaScript строка поддерживает протокол итерации, который разбивает её на символы, независимые от кодировки (code points). Поэтому попробуйте:

```
var textar = [...text];
```

Подробнее можно почитать:

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!) – Joel on Software](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

[What every JavaScript developer should know about Unicode](https://dmitripavlutin.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-unicode/)

[JavaScript has a Unicode problem · Mathias Bynens](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode)

[Unicode-aware regular expressions in ES2015 · Mathias Bynens](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex)

[ES6 Strings (and Unicode, ❤) in Depth](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-strings-and-unicode-in-depth)

[Jonathan New | "".length === 2](https://blog.jonnew.com/posts/poo-dot-length-equals-two)

P.S. Если вы ограничены использованием ES5, можно попробовать комбинацию из полифилов [`String.prototype.codePointAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt#Polyfill) + [`String.fromCodePoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint#Polyfill) по сылкам (т.е. `text.split("")[4]` заменить на `String.fromCodePoint(text.codePointAt(4))`).

Comment: Google Apps Script не умеет больше чем в ES5.

Comment: @oshliaer Простите, не учёл. Добавил в конце ответа возможный выход.

Comment: Возможно, это лучший подход в данном случае.

Comment: Да, помогло, теперь отображается верно.
Благодарю за помощь